# Which merge modules to use for a Crystal Reports XI deployment with a VB6 application?

Tags: deployment, vb6, crystal-reports

In the VB application I use the CRAXDRT.dll and a ReportViewerControl on a form. Which merge modules do I need?

Comment: Did you create formulas in Crystal, and if so do you use Crystal syntax or VB syntax, I have been told it makes a difference in the files required. I am not sure I remember correctly, but you may only need crpe.dll if you used Crystal syntax.

Comment: The report itself does some database operations, but it is simply called up with the CRAXDRT.Application's Load command. Furthermore, a CrystalReports Control is used on a form to show it. What I find frustrating that I have been unable to find a comprehensive guide that specifies how to use CR XI from VB6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of CR XI you're using, but mine came with the following merge modules:

```
CR11_rdc_designtime.msm
CR11_rdc_license.msm
CR11_rdc_reportengine.msm
CR11_rdc_runtime.msm
```

These should all be located in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules` if they are installed.  You will only need the license and runtime modules if all you're doing is generating existing reports, but it's been a while since I've messed with this so you might need the reportengine module.  Within the license module, you may have to provide your Crystal Reports license key before it can be included in the installation (I know this to be true with InstallShield 2008).

If these files are not present, I'm thinking installing the merge modules was an advanced setup option within the Crystal Reports installation, as I'm pretty sure they were not installed by default.  Unfortunately I don't have my CRXI setup discs available to check for sure.

Comment: Thanks! I do have these merge modules in the folder you specified,it is also possible to download them from http://resources.businessobjects.com /support/additional_downloads/runtime. Then you will get even a fifth merge module. As building the .msi's and testing them is painfully slow I have not yet tried making the 5! permutations to see which combination both works and and has the minimal download length....

Comment: Our app requires all four of these modules which builds to a compressed MSI size of 66MB.  `designtime` is only required if you are using the `CRAXDDRT.dll` (embeddable designer) in your project, and `reportengine` is only required if you're doing any exporting.  This is what they say at least, I've never tried it to see how small it builds with just `license` and `runtime`.

Comment: I have decided to leave it and just build the .msi with all the merge files. It is certainly possible that functionality that is not needed now, will be needed later.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Package & Deployment wizard, it should be able to pick up all the necessary dependency files for you.

I am sorry, its been some time that I worked on VB6.

Comment: The strange thing is that some of the dependencies are not present on the development computer, while it works without problems.